# Can Meteor.loginWithPassword be changed to return a generic error?

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor, the **Meteor.loginWithPassword** function calls the server, which then returns a `User not found` error when the user does not exist, or a `Match failed` when the password does not match the user's password.

Is there an easy way for the server to return the **same** error (or no error) during **both** conditions of a failed login?

I don't want hackers to know when they found a valid username or UserID on my system.  I don't want the server to say `User not found`, telling potential hackers when they have (or have not) found a valid user.  It would be great if there's an easy way to change the error message the server returns from the **accounts-password** Meteor module, to harden the security a little bit.  I'd like the server's error result to be something generic, like `failed` or undefined or null, regardless of the reason of the login error.

I know I can probably fork/re-purpose the accounts-password module, but hoping there's something simpler.

Thanks!

Comment: Other than re-purposing the `accounts-password` module, I think it may be possible to create a custom login system using [`this`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/advanced_accounts_api).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can place the function somewhere in the /server-folder and change the error message. Like this:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(options) {
  if (!options.allowed) { //that is, if there's an error
    throw new Meteor.Error('login-error', 'Error!');
  }
//...other code for other purposes below
});
```

/server/accounts.js